# Algorithm for re-arranging a sequence of weights

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I have a number of items in an array, each one associated to a certain weight. There is a business rule saying that no two adjacent items cannot have a total weight of more than a certain value, let's say 100 for simplicity.

For example, the following is OK:

```
[40,60,40,50]
```

But not this one (since 50+60 = 110)

```
[50,60,40]
```

I am trying to implement an algorithm that will rearrange the items (if possible) so that the business rule is fulfilled. For example, the second one could be rearranged to
  [60,40,50] or [50,40,60]

The algorithm should also tres to minimize the number of moved items, i.e. the first solution above is most appropriate since the "sub permutation" `[60,40]` is maintained.

I'm not looking for a complete answer or code examples, but would be happy if someone could point out some algorithms or categories of algorithms for this purpose. It would feel much better to rely on an existing and proved algorithm than some home-made stuff.

Note: In reality, the number of items is very large so testing all different permutations is NOT an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice greedy solution: for the first place take maximum number. For each next place take maximum from untaken numbers before that satisfy your condition. If you place all numbers - you have found a solution. Otherwise the solution doesn't exist, why - it's an exercise for you.

My proof: imagine a solution exists. Show, that my algorithm will find it. Let's a_1, ..., a_n - any solution. Let a_i - maximum element. Then a_i, a_{i-1}, ..., a_1, a_{i+1}, a_{i+2}, ..., a_n is a solution too, because a_1 <= a_i, a_1 + a_{i+1} <= a_i + a_{i+1}, so (a_i, a_{i+1}) is a good pair. Next, let a_1, ..., a_j is element according to my solution. Show, that a_{j+1} can be element, as my solution suppose to. Let a_i - maximum from a_{j+1}, .., a_n. Then a_1, ..., a_j, a_i, a_{i-1}, ..., a{j+1}, a_{i+1}, ..., a_n is a solution too. It shows that algo always find solution.

Comment: Gah! I hate it when people do that. Why? Because not only do I have to do the work but often, it means they're not sure either!

Comment: @quasiverse, not exactly. I know proof, but I don't want to spend time to explain unnecessary things. I want author of question to prove it himself and if he fail I'll post the proof. It's quiet easy to proof that fact, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, mispressed enter and can edit comments 1 time per 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok, that's my proof: imagine a solution exists. Show, that my algorithm will find it. Let's a_1, ..., a_n - any solution. Let a_i - maximum element. Then a_i, a_{i-1}, ..., a_1, a_{i+1}, a_{i+2}, ..., a_n is a solution too, because a_1 <= a_i, a_1 + a_{i+1} <= a_i + a_{i+1}, so (a_i, a_{i+1}) is a good pair. Next, let a_1, ..., a_j is element according to my solution. Show, that a_{j+1} can be element, as my solution suppose to. Let a_i - maximum from a_{j+1}, .., a_n. Then a_1, ..., a_j, a_i, a_{i-1}, ..., a{j+1}, a_{i+1}, ..., a_n is a solution too. It shows that algo always find solution.

Comment: @Artem: Thanks a lot man! I'll check this out too (and thanks for the proof) :)

Comment: -1: [50,1 60] where the limit is 100. Your greedy algorithm will fail.

Comment: @Moron It will find [60, 1, 50]. What fail are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

Big items can only be next to small items.

1. Sort the list
2. Cut in half
3. Reverse second half
4. Swap halves
5. Shuffle (take first item from each half, repeat)

Example: [1,3,8,4,2,4,1,7]

1. [1,1,2,3,4,4,7,8]
2. [1,1,2,3] [4,4,7,8]
3. [1,1,2,3] [8,7,4,4]
4. [8,7,4,4] [1,1,2,3]
5. [8,1,7,1,4,2,4,3]

I'm pretty sure you can't do better than this. If the business rule is violated anyway there is no solution. Prove/Counterexample left as an exercise ;-)

Edit: Take biggest item first!

Comment: That is what I thought, Highest and Lowest values should not break the rule in theory.

Comment: @LumpN I pretty sure this would break for 1,2,7,8 when the max is 9. The algorithm will give 1,8,2,7 which has 8+2=10>9 while it can actually be solved with 8,1,2,7. This should be able to be fixed trivially though by taking the items of the second list first to give 8,1,7,2 which is correct as well.

Comment: I like it! Really simple (in a good way) and easy to explain. However, for "simple" sequences (where it's enough to move one item) there must be a solution that preserves the original sequence in a better way. Maybe I'll go for a combination, where your solution will work as a "last resort"....

Comment: @quasiverse: Good point exploiting the list-boundaries by placing the biggest item first.

Comment: @Artem Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: +1: This could be right (please include a proof). Take max, then min, then second max, then second min etc.  Of course, it does not minimize the number of moves, though.

Comment: @Moron. I think proof is similar to proof of my solution. First number is maximum one. Second - smallest from the unused before, third - largest from unused and so on. We show, that if any solution exist, we can reverse part of its' numbers to get LumpN's sequence.

Comment: @Artem: I only want the answer to include a proof for the sake of completeness :-). I suggest you add your proof to your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to a bin packing problem, take a look at (eg) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fit_algorithm

I'm pretty sure it's not the same, but it may give you some clues.

You also need to consider what would happen if a sigle item is over the limit - how would you deal with that?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out. If one item is over the limit there's not much to do I guess...should not happen in real-life scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading in from a data file and find an exception(a value which is larger than the goal value) then you could either choose to kill the program or exclude it. Also, the solution provided by LumpN could be tweaked by switching up the last step if the previous solution failed. Basically shuffling backwards.